# Power Automate to convert date to dd mm yyyy

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

Can you please help?

I am trying to convert the date format using PowerAutomate.

I have a sharepoint list with multiple columns, every time it creates an entry it sends an email.

For example in my sharepoint list it stores date as 20/03/2024
What I'm trying to do is when it sending the email it needs to convert to 20 March 2024 and add it to the email.

I have tried this code

```
if(empty(triggerBody()?['From']), 
'No Date Available', 
formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['From'], 'dd MM  yyyy'))
```

But it when I receive the email it shows No Date Available,

I have tested placing above expression and also default Dynamic content value.

Dynamic content value shows the date as 2024-03-19
But he expression shows as No Date Available.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: Can you show us trigger data? We’re punching in the dark without it.

Comment: @Skin Just added a screenshot, is that what you after?

Comment: That’s not the trigger data, I want to see the json from the trigger.

Comment: I had a look, in JSON it states Date Required From eventhough I have renamed it to From,  it still picking the old name. 

Thanks for reminding me to check the JSON data

Comment: So you fixed it, yes?

Comment: @Asanka, you have to use **internal name** of SharePoint columns in Power Automate expressions. Check: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).